# Using ngModel over multiple (looped) inputs

Tags: angular

[This is the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO3eo.png) 
I tried to make my table dynamic, as I do not know how many memberships my client would want. The problem is when I tried to use ngModel, all inputs are the same. Need help finding some solutions/workaround.

```
<tbody *ngIf="membershipList">
  <tr *ngFor="let member of membershipList;">
    <td class="text-center valign-middle">{{member.membership_name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let list of membershipList;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" [(ngModel)]="test">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is your membershipList an array of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, add index to the test so it's always a new one.

```
   <tr *ngFor="let member of membershipList; let i = index;">
    <td class="text-center valign-middle">{{member.membership_name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let list of membershipList;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" [(ngModel)]="test" + i>
    </td>
  </tr>
```